# How to use a function and expression in a ngClass using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-class

I'm currently trying to show a list of Pokemons that have a different background color depending on their type. I would like to implement a feature where the border of the selected pokemon also shows with a gold border color. If I use them one at a time they work just fine but i'm having trouble using them together.

My html is the following:

```html
<h1>Pokédex</h1>
<p [hidden]="!selectedPokemon">Geselecteerde pokemon: {{selectedPokemon}}</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-pokemon (selectedPokemon)="highlightPokemon($event)"
               *ngFor="let item of pokemons"
               [pokemon]="item"
               [ngClass]="{getType(item.type), item.name === selectedPokemon ? 'select' : ''}">
  </app-pokemon>
</div>
```

My getType function is the following:

```js
getType(pokemonType: string): string {
    pokemonType = pokemonType.toLowerCase();
    switch(pokemonType) {
      case 'grass': {
        return 'grass'
      }
      case 'fire': {
        return 'fire'
      }
      case 'water': {
        return 'water'
      }
      default: {
        return 'grass'
      }
    }
  }
```

The error my IDE is complaining about:

[image]

I also tried the following:

```html
[ngClass]="getType(item.type), item.name === selectedPokemon ? 'select' : ''">
```

[image]

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of calling function : getType(item.type) inside HTML template , you can follow this example maybe it helps : codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/ng-class+switch+case

Comment: @RebaiAhmed What would be the better way of doing it? Do you have an example of how it should be done?

Comment: I added this link in my previous comment : https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/ng-class+switch+case you can check it ,it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using [className]="getType(item.type)" and [class.select]="item.name === selectedPokemon"

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Pokédex</h1>
<p [hidden]="!selectedPokemon">Geselecteerde pokemon: {{selectedPokemon}}</p>
<div class="wrapper">
<app-pokemon (selectedPokemon)="highlightPokemon($event)"
           *ngFor="let item of pokemons"
           [pokemon]="item"
class="{{getType(item.type)}}"
           [ngClass]="item.name === selectedPokemon ? 
'select' : ''">
</app-pokemon>
</div>
```

this is working code, what i did is selected class will come from ngclass while background class will come through getType function

Answer (score 0):

using functions in html templates is a bad practice, try to dont use them.
but you can use like this for add multiple class conditionally by ngClass in angular

```
<div [ngClass]="[yourFunction(value), value === 2 && 'your-class']">123</div>
```

Comment: What would be the better way of doing it? Do you have an example of how it should be done?

Comment: there is a good article for this subject on medium : https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=Because%20expression%20are%20so%20powerful,our%20views%20become%20more%20complex.&text=While%20function%20calls%20in%20Angular,may%20cause%20serious%20performance%20issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions in the ngclass using the following syntax

*home.html*

```
<ion-item >
   <ion-input (ionFocus)="openJobOrderMeters($event)" formControlName="jobordermeter" [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': isInvalid('jobordermeter')}" placeholder="Job Order/ Account Number"
   value="{{ joborder }}" ></ion-input>
   <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

home.ts file

```
isInvalid(controlName: string): boolean {
  const control = this.smartmeterform.get(controlName);
  return control.invalid && control.touched;
```

}

Every time it calls the isInvalid function written in the home.ts file and acts according to the value returned by it. I have been marking the fields that are touched and it does not have valid input yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).